# Android web browser: Menu options don't pop up

Tags: android, html, browser, menu

I'm having a problem with [a web page I'm developing, a Price Per Unit Calculator](http://www.whitegloveapps.com/priceper/priceperdev.html) (in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript/jQuery): When viewed in the Android 2.3.3 default web browser, the menus near the top of the page, Unit type and Display unit, aren't popping up (to let the user select an item from the menu). This problem occurs in both the Android emulator and an Android phone running 2.3.3. The menus work fine with later versions of the Android web browser I've tested (4.0.3 and 4.2 in the emulator), as well as in iOS 6 and on a computer (Firefox and Chrome browsers tested).

In the Android 2.3.3 web browser, when a menu is tapped, a colored rectangle should highlight the menu on the web page, then the menu options pop up in a list on the screen. On my web page, for those menus near the top of the page, the rectangle appears (wider than the menu that was tapped), but seems to stop when it hits the bottom of the div (row) the menu is in, and no menu options pop up; see the orange rectangle in [this screenshot](http://www.whitegloveapps.com/priceper/android-menu-fail.jpg). The menus lower in the web page work fine.

Here's the simplified HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="global">
        <div id="unitTypeDiv" class="options col1 unit"><!-- left column-->
                <label for="unitType" class="label">Unit type</label><br>
    <select name="unitType" id="unitType" class="unitType_input" title="Unit type">
                    <option value="weight">weight</option>
                    <option value="volume">volume</option>
                    <option value="length">length</option>
                    <option value="area">area</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div id="displayUnitDiv" class="options col2 unit"><!-- center column-->
                <span id="displayUnitLabel"><label for="displayUnit" class="label">Display unit</label><br></span>
                <select name="displayUnit" id="displayUnit" class="displayUnit_input unit_input" title="Display unit">
                    <option value="oz">oz</option>
                    <option value="lb">lb</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>   <!-- .global -->

    </div> <!-- .header -->
    <div id="products">

        <form method="post" name="priceper" id="priceper">

            <div class="product" id="product_0">
                <div class="name">
                    <label for="name_0" class="label"><span>Product 1:</span> Name<br></label>
                    <input name="name_0" type="text" id="name_0" title="Product 1">
                </div>
                <div class="unit row">
                    <label for="unit_0" class="label">Unit</label><br>
                    <select name="unit_0" id="unit_0" class="unit_input product_unit_input" title="Please choose a unit"> <!--replace with select (pop-up menu)-->
                        <option value="oz">oz</option>
                        <option value="lb">lb</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

            </div> <!--product_0-->

        </form>

    </div> <!-- products -->
```

Edit: Here's the CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: #222;
    font-family: Helvetica; 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* HEADER STYLES */
    .header {
        position:fixed; /* Keep header (title) at top of page always */
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index:99998; /* Bring to front */
        /*border: 1px dashed red;*/
    }
    .header h1 {
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
        text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #fff;
        /*background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, 
                                           from(#ccc), to(red));*/ /* iPhone linear shading; not working*/
        /*border: 1px dashed red;*/
        margin-top: -3px;
        margin-bottom: -3px;
        background-color: #ccc;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-bottom:3px;
        text-align: center;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
    }
    .header h1 a {
        color: #222;
        display: block;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .global {
        /*border: 1px dashed red;*/
        background-color: #eee; /* Background color */
        height: 43px;
        padding-top: 0px;
        z-index: 9999;
        /*border-bottom: 1px solid #666;*/
    }
    .col1 {     /* Unit type menu */
        float: left;
        margin-left: 5px;
        /*border: 1px dashed red;*/
    }
    .col2 {     /* Display unit menu */
        float: none;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-align:center;
        /*display: table-cell;*/
        /*border: 1px dashed green;*/
        position: absolute;
        /* center on browser window: put left at 50%, then offset left (margin-left) by half the width (half of 30% = 15%) */
        width: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -25%;
    }

/* PRODUCT STYLES */
    .product {
        padding-top: 2px;
        padding-bottom: 3px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
        background-color: #DCDCDC;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;
        color: #222222;
    }
    #product_0 {
        margin-top: 100px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the Android 2.3.3 web browser didn't like the last CSS property, `margin-top`, on a div, `#product_0`, below the one the problematic menus were in. Simply changing the property to `padding-top` worked:

```
    #product_0 {
        padding-top: 100px;
    }
```

[Here's the resulting web page (full version rather than simplified code).](http://www.whitegloveapps.com/priceper/priceperdev.html)